# Gwt custom text box having baloon popup

Tags: java, gwt

how to make a custom text box in Google web toolkit(gwt) having balloon feature of displaying error messages?

i am using Google web toolkit(gwt) in java on eclipse and i don't see any function providing this functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "balloon feature" ?

Comment: by baloon i mean displaying error message with a popup like thing(tooltip)

Comment: Check this http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~PopupPanel

Answer (score 2):

You should implement your own "composite". To "compose" a "balloon"/tooltip with the inputs of your form.

Here is an example of the ui.xml for a text area using Gwt-bootstrap. (Doing the same in plain GWT is straightforward, if not, I'll be glad to convert this example).

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui">    
<b:WellForm>
        <b:Fieldset>
            <b:ControlGroup>
                <b:Label styleName="field_label" ui:field="label" />
                <b:TextArea ui:field="myWidget"/>
                <b:HelpInline ui:field="errorMessage" visible="false" />                    
            </b:ControlGroup>
        </b:Fieldset>
    </b:WellForm>
```

If by "balloon" you mean "tooltip", then add a mouseOverHandler and a mouseOutHandler to display/hide the error message (HelpInline here, but could be any widget) when there is one to display.

If you are satisfied with this you should implement some inheritance mechanism to reuse everything around this tag

```
<b:TextArea b:id="textArea" ui:field="textArea"/>
```

for all kinds of widgets.

By using composite you can have a single line reused for all error messages ("balloons" or something else) for all your input widgets, and switch between HelpInline, Label, etc easily.

**EDIT**

The sample code with plain GWT

```
 <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
        xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">   
 <g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="widgetContainer">
      <g:Label styleName="field_label" ui:field="label" />
      <g:TextArea ui:field="myWidget"/>
      <g:Label ui:field="errorMessage" visible="false" />
 </g:HorizontalPanel>
```

I suggest using a HorizontalPanel to display the field's label (ui:field="label"), the input field itself (ui:field="myWidget") and the error message (ui:field="errorMessage") on one line, but other kind of panels are also possible, or you can use CSS to position the elements as you want.

Comment: can you do in simple GWT as you mentioned?

Comment: Sure. I edited my answer. If you have more questions feel free to ask. This example use UiBinder. If you are not used to UiBinder, maybe you would prefer plain Java ?

Comment: i am not able to understand this . Can u tell me the procedure of using plugin of javascript,css or jquery. I want to make a new customized textbox extending the old one with tooltip functionality.What i need is when some error occurs on typing  and when we click on submit button tooltip is displayed next to textbox displaying error

Comment: Sorry I didn't touch JQuery in a long while. You can either try to post a new question with the "jquery" tag or try to explain what it is you don't understand (is it the ui:UiBinder stuff ? the programming logic behind ? ...)

Comment: the problem is i want to display a bubble type tooltip but you are talking displaying a label like stuff .

Comment: You can design the label (just a <span>) as a bubble using CSS.