# How do i add a tooltip to existing gwt Textbox?

Tags: java, gwt

my application is using eclipse with gwt plugin included. Currently it has a simple textbox without tool tip functionality.

Do i have to import a plugin of j query or java script file? If yes provide the procedure

or How can i make a customized text box using all this?

i tried using Qtip but did not succeed as i am quite new to javascript,css and html

Answer (score 7):

You can do this easily in GWT - use the `setTitle()` method:

```
textBox.setTitle("Tooltip text");
```

This method is available on any `UIObject` - no point introducing external JS libraries when you don't have to. (You can mix them with GWT, but it gets quite complicated quite quickly!)

Comment: i want to display bubble tooltip on click on a button not on hovering as told by you.

Comment: i want to display bubble tooltip  and i want to display tooltip on click on some other button as i want to display some error messages in it? For ex email entered is wrong

Answer (score 0):

For a nice tooltip (other than the HTML default) you can use a composite widget. You'll find examples with GWT-Bootstrap and plain GWT at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186155/gwt-custom-text-box-having-baloon-popup).

Comment: i want to display bubble tooltip, will i be able to do it using bootstrap or ui binder?   and i want to display tooltip on click on some other button as i want to display some error messages in it? For ex email entered is wrong